# Hive Mind and Counterspell

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let say I have [Hive Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHive%20Mind%5d) in game:

[image]

The opponent casts Counterspell on my creature spell. Can I counter the Counterspell with the clone of Counterspell I get from Hive Mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. By the time [Hive Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHive%20Mind%5d)'s ability copies your opponent's [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d), that Counterspell is already on the stack. So you can choose it as a target for your own copy of Counterspell.

In more detail, what happens is this:

1. You cast your creature spell, which let's say is a [Weirded Vampire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWeirded%20Vampire%5d). (Why would you be playing Weirded Vampire against Hive Mind? Weird, huh.) The stack is

   - Weirded Vampire
2. Your opponent casts Counterspell, and Hive Mind's ability triggers. The stack is

   - Hive Mind's ability
   - Counterspell (opponent's)
   - Weirded Vampire
3. The ability resolves, giving you a copy of Counterspell, which you can choose to have target the original Counterspell. The stack is

   - Counterspell (yours)
   - Counterspell (opponent's)
   - Weirded Vampire
4. Your Counterspell resolves, countering your opponent's Counterspell. The stack is

   - Weirded Vampire
5. The Weirded Vampire now resolves.

This does mean that (in a 2-player game) Hive Mind basically nullifies any counterspell which can target a copy of itself.